# How to conditionally format a field in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word file (doc or docx) that follows a specific name pattern.
The pattern is:

```
 XXXXXXX_X_XXXXXXXX_NNNNNNN_NNNNNNN_XXXXXXXXX.doc(x)
```

and an example is:

```
 Contract_J_Smith_01032022_31032022_GOOGLE.doc(x)
```

My intention is to create a macro in Word that will get the name of the file, split it in parts by the underscore (_) and then create two variables (startdate and enddate) with the 4th and 5th parts of the filename in order to use them inside the document.
These parts are dates in the format **ddMMyyyy**.
Also, I want to check if these variables represent a true date, so if they are true, the variable remains as it is and if they are false, a warning text will replace the variable inside the document.
This warning text should be bold and red.
So far I have managed to write the following code:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Dim aStory As Range
    Dim aField As Field
    Dim fname As String
    Dim startdate As String
    Dim enddate As String
    fname = ActiveDocument.Name
    startdate = Split(fname, "_")(3)
    enddate = Split(fname, "_")(4)
    startdate = Left(startdate, 2) & "/" & Mid(startdate, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(startdate, 4)
    enddate = Left(enddate, 2) & "/" & Mid(enddate, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(enddate, 4)
    If IsDate(startdate) = False Then
        startdate = "Problem with start date in filename"
    End If
    If IsDate(enddate) = False Then
        enddate = "Problem with end date in filename"
    End If
    With ActiveDocument
        .Variables("startdate").Value = startdate
    End With
    With ActiveDocument
        .Variables("enddate").Value = enddate
    End With
    For Each aStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each aField In aStory.Fields
            aField.Update
        Next aField
    Next aStory
End Sub
```

The only things that are missing are making the text bold and red.
Any suggestions?

Comment: VBA strings contain only text.  They do not contain aany formatting information.  If you need Bold, Red text, this is a 'Style' issue that can only be addressed in Word itself.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to wrap the DOCVARIABLE fields in your document in an IF field, as shown below.

Here is a link to [documentation on the IF Field](https://support.microsoft.com/office/9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e) if you are not familiar with it.

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting. Can you put the code in text and not as image?

Comment: That wouldn't help you as you cannot copy and paste field codes from here. Use Ctrl+F9 to insert a field.

Comment: Here is a free Add-In that converts field codes to text and vice-versa. http://www.gmayor.com/export_field.htm It has the code as well.

Comment: Conditional formatting is far easier in Excel. IF fields that give the text in different formats, as shown are the only way I know.